# Why does Github webhooks give me circular JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, ecmascript-6, webhooks

With the below code I am trying to get some basic pull request info from my Github repo, when someone submits a pull request for it. But I get this output instead:

```
$ node poc2.js 
sha1=fef5611617bf56a36d165f73d41e527ee2c97d49
res [Circular]
req [Circular]
```

Since the secret hash is printed, the webhook is received. I can also verifiy this by `nc -l 8080` instead of running my NodeJS app. There is will see a large json object, which is from where I got the json structure I use in the `console.log`'s below.

## Question

Can anyone figure out, why I get a "circular" json object from both `req` and `res`?

And how can I get the values I `console.log`?

```
const secret = "sdfsfsfsfwerwergdgv";

const http = require('http');
const crypto = require('crypto');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        let sig = "sha1=" + crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret).update(chunk.toString()).digest('hex');
        console.log(sig);
        if (req.headers['x-hub-signature'] == sig) {
          console.log("res %j", res);
          console.log("req %j", req);
          if (res.action == 'opened') {

            console.log('PR for: ' + res.repository.html_url);
            console.log('PR for: ' + res.repository.full_name);

            console.log('PR: ' + res.pull_request.html_url);
            console.log('PR title: ' + res.pull_request.title);
            console.log('PR description' + res.pull_request.description);
            console.log('PR by user: ' + res.pull_request.user.login);
          };
        }
    });

    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, there cannot possibly be a "circular JSON object:". There can however be JavaScript object graphs involving circular references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `req` is circular because it's *not a JSON object*, it's the [Request object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) which includes a lot of internal machinery, some of which is circularly linked.

The actual incoming JSON document is in `req.body` or wherever your particular [JSON body parser puts it](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json), though in this example you don't have one yet so that's something you should fix.

> Tip: You may want to use [Express](https://expressjs.com) instead of the core Node `http` module, it's much more capable.